# create border and labels for groups of features in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, labeling

I am relatively new to GIS, so please bear with me if my question is a basic one.

I have a simple map of the parishes (counties) in Louisiana, and each of the parishes has an associated regional area which is denoted by a number. Using the symbology tab in properties, I was able to color each of the regions. However, now I need to do two things:

1) Embolden the borders between each of the regions to help make the distinctions more clear (while leaving the borders between the parishes as is)
2) Label each of the regions with their regional number. When I currently try to do this, a little number label pops up in each of the parishes rather than just one number for each region.

I am using Arcmap 10 on a windows 7 PC. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding your question correctly your parish layer has a separate field which represents regions.  If that is the case you could just use the Dissolve tool to dissolve by the region field.  This will give you a separate region layer which you can label and symbolize differently from your parish layer.

Comment: yup, dissolve worked perfectly. so simple. thanks.